# Implementing rights management in class design

Tags: sql-server, database, class-design, rights-management

I have to do a Project where there will be a number of users who will use the application. Users can belong to either Users, Executive or Administrator. Each Usergroup has their own rights. All data will be stored in a database.

Now I am doing the class design and I dont know if I have to design a right as a class in itself or if I should just watch for the usergroup and then just deny or allow access to CRUD operations in the database.

What would be a good way to implement a right that refers to a user or group?

Comment: How will you be authenticating your users, and what degree of security would be necessary? SQL Server's built-in security would give greater confidence, but if your app can't support it then the choices are different...

Comment: i planned to use a kind of preventive security. like the user cant see buttons which he shouldn't have access to. the admins, for example, have controls that enable them to add users, the execs and users do not. what i have planned is that when a form is loading, it checks the rights of the user sitting in front of it, then it generates the forms according to the user's group.

Comment: Sure, well leaving discussion on defence-in-depth aside you don't have any real requirements to harden the database so you're probably just as well going with whatever-framework-you're-using's authorization behaviours and trying very hard not to obscure it - they're typically well understood and likely documented better anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Design classes that meet your business requirements. I imagine some "UI facing" classes that allow the user screen to be configured. On the database end I don't know if "rights have users" or "users have rights"; design to your business model. Of course you'll need grunt-code to map to info from the DB.

> design a right as a class in itself or...

Depends on how complex that class is. ... I'd say the `UserGroup` class will have a `List` of rights, be it a collection of complex objects or merely enums. If all your business model needs is to ask "what rights does Bob have?" then a List of enums sounds good to me. The alternative to an enum is a `Right` base class, subclassed for every right. Too much work for such a trivial use, IMHO.

If you're uncertain which way to go then make a separate class that encapsulates the List of rights. The "API" it exposes to the rest of your application will not be changing if/when you go from enums to a `Right` class, back and fourth.